# Specifying a WHERE clause after a JOIN clause - Active Record - CodeIgniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I wanted to ask is it possible to specify a where clause after a join in order to match data to a users input. Say for example I have the following code:

```
 $this->db->select('user.*,role.*')
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where('user.username', $username);
  $this->db->where('user.password', $password);
  $this->db->join('role','role.id = user.role_id')
  $result = $this->db->get();
```

and I want to query the matching data from the table 'role':

```
 $this->db->select('user.*,role.*')
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where('user.username', $username);
  $this->db->where('user.password', $password);
  $this->db->join('role','role.id = user.role_id')
  $this->db->where('role.speaker', $speaker); //want to know if this is correct
  $result = $this->db->get();
```

Is this possible? Can I compare results (using WHERE) after a JOIN? Will that produce results matching to the WHERE clause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't actually build the query until `->get()` is called.  You can call the methods in whatever order you want.